# Fixed position for button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make button fixed using `margin-bottom` but it's not working if there is longer title.

My example: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGHTW.jpg)

```
<div class="post-detail-container-div">
<br />
<div class="post-content-div">
<h3 class="post-title entry-title">
   <a href="vijest?id=<?php echo $p['link'];?>"><?php echo $p['naslov']; ?></a>
</h3>
<div class="spusti">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline post-metadata">
      <li>
         <i class="far fa-calendar"></i> Mon, 06-09-2018&nbsp;&nbsp;| 
      </li>
      <li>
         <i class="far fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;
         <a href="#">Comments(10)</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p class="post-excerpt"> <?php echo $p['uvodni_tekst'];?> </p>
   <hr>
   <div class="view_detail">
      <a href="vijest?id=<?php echo $p['link'];?>" class="blog-btn">Pročitaj više</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you check photo you can see that button's are not in same line because title is longer.

My CSS class view_detail:

```
.view_detail {
     text-align:  center;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
```

I'm using bootstrap too, so every suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Give a fixed height to upper content part or set position absolute and give left and bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

- add `position: relative;` to the main card container
- add `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to the button container
- to avoid the overlap of the button set the `margin-bottom` of the text part as the height of the button container